# Multiple CSS Modal boxes

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

So I was reading the following article: [Create Modal window with CSS3](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/)

However, I'm wanting to modify it by adding more than one modal box to my site.

Here is the code to the original modal:

```
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Modal Box</h2>
    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
    <p>etc..etc..</p>
</div>
```

There is no CSS call for the `<div id=openModal"`
To create multiple modals, my assumption would be to change the div to `<div id=openModal2" class="modalDialog2">`

The styling is only on the modalDialog box, So for a second modal, I would assume I'd change the class name for that too.

However, every time I do this, it does not open the modal box.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="#openModal1">Box 1</a>

<div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog1">
<div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Modal Box 1</h2>
    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.    </p>
    <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
</div>
</div>
<a href="#openModal2">Box 2</a>

  <div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog2">
<div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Modal Box 2</h2>
    <p><strong>Box 2</strong></p>
    <p>yadda yadda</p>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't have to change the class. The role of classes is to apply the same style to different elements, so keeping it `modalDialog` will do the job.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3Vykc/

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem about an hour ago, right before reading this article. I didn't change the class at all, as indicated in the answer above. I simply created a new ID (with some new properties) for the second modal box and it worked fine.

This said, I ran into this article because I'm having a problem with overflow: scroll/auto only in Chrome with some iframed (yuck, but I have no choice, it comes from a third-party credit card vendor I have to use on this project) content for the modal box. Now if anyone has a solution for this one...    :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. S.O. is a Q&A site, not a forum, so [it works a little differently](http://stackoverflow.com/about). This area is only for posting *answers* to the original thread. (Non-answers posted in this section are usually deleted). Since it sounds like you have a *question*, it is best to use the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) option instead. If needed, you can link to this thread for context. To ensure the best response, please review [Ask] before posting.

Comment: Hm... actually on second read it looks like your first paragraph suggests an alternate solution. Sorry, my bad. I was thrown off by the question in the second paragraph :)

Comment: @Leigh, still, answers should be very clear. Stephen, you could edit this if it is indeed an answer to make it more clear; otherwise, you should remove it. Good luck!

Comment: @jmort253 - Agreed. Stephen S.O.'s format is more spartan than a forum. "Nothin' but questions and answers" ;-) If you could clarify by editing/deleting the post, that would be great.